# Error in Loading Dynamic feature. App Bundle Android

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

In Android `API` level, 26 (Oreo) and above I am getting this error. If I run dynamic feature from android studio direct to the device, the dynamic feature works fine, but when I upload app bundle on play store and try to run dynamic feature from the app which downloaded from play store I am  getting

> Runtime Exception: Resources$ NotFoundException on every resource
>   (string.xml, atrr.xml etc).

Below Android API level, 26 its working fine.

Error Log:

> 2018-08-27 18:23:41.097 20926-20926/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.ak.ta.dainikbhaskar.activity.release, PID: 20926
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ak.ta.dainikbhaskar.activity.release/com.dainik.bhaskar.fitness.activities.EntryActivity}:
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID
>
> ## 0x7e0b000e
>
> ```
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2792)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2870)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1601)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6590)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7e0b000e
>     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:339)
>     at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:433)
>     at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:556)
>     at com.dainik.bhaskar.fitness.activities.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:34)
>     at com.dainik.bhaskar.fitness.activities.EntryActivity.onCreate(EntryActivity.java:31)
>     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
>     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7014)
>     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2745)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2870)
>
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1601) 
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172) 
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6590) 
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
> ```

code:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
SplitInstallManager installManager;
String EpaperModuleName = "epaper_dynamic_lib";
private final String EPaperLauncherclassName = "com.bhaskar.epaper.ui.SplashActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    (findViewById(R.id.btn_epaper)).setOnClickListener(this);
    installManager = SplitInstallManagerFactory.create(this);
    installManager.registerListener(splitInstallStateUpdatedListener);

}


private void loadAndLaunchModule(String moduleName, String launcherclassName) {
    // Skip loading if the module already is installed. Perform success action directly.
    if (installManager.getInstalledModules().contains(moduleName)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onSuccessfulLoad " + moduleName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        onSuccessfulLoad(moduleName, launcherclassName, true);
        return;
    }

    // Create request to install a feature module by name.
    SplitInstallRequest request = SplitInstallRequest.newBuilder()
            .addModule(moduleName)
            .build();

    // Load and install the requested feature module.
    installManager.startInstall(request);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "startInstall " + moduleName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private final SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener splitInstallStateUpdatedListener = new SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStateUpdate(SplitInstallSessionState splitInstallSessionState) {
        List<String> splitModules = splitInstallSessionState.moduleNames();

        boolean multiInstall = splitModules.size() > 1;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "multiInstall " + multiInstall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        for (String moduleName : splitModules) {

            int status = splitInstallSessionState.status();
            if (status == SplitInstallSessionStatus.DOWNLOADING) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading " + moduleName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (status == SplitInstallSessionStatus.REQUIRES_USER_CONFIRMATION) {
                try {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "REQUIRES_USER_CONFIRMATION " + moduleName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startIntentSender(splitInstallSessionState.resolutionIntent().getIntentSender(), null,
                            0, 0, 0);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (status == SplitInstallSessionStatus.INSTALLED) {

                    onSuccessfulLoad(moduleName, EPaperLauncherclassName, true);


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "INSTALLED " + moduleName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (status == SplitInstallSessionStatus.INSTALLING) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "INSTALLING " + moduleName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (status == SplitInstallSessionStatus.FAILED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FAILED " + moduleName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "Error: " + splitInstallSessionState.errorCode() + "for module " + moduleName);
            }
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Request uninstall of all features.
 */
private void requestUninstall(final String moduleName) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requesting uninstall of all modules." +
            "This will happen at some point in the future.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    final Set<String> installedModules = installManager.getInstalledModules();
    installManager.deferredUninstall(new ArrayList<String>(installedModules)).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uninstalling " + moduleName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Define what to do once a feature module is loaded successfully.
 *
 * @param moduleName The name of the successfully loaded module.
 * @param launch     `true` if the feature module should be launched, else `false`.
 */
private void onSuccessfulLoad(String moduleName, String launcherclassName, boolean launch) {
    if (launch) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onSuccessfulLoad " + moduleName,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            launchActivity(launcherclassName);

    }

}

/**
 * Launch an activity by its class name.
 */
private void launchActivity(String className) {

    try {


        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClassName(this.getPackageName(), className);
        startActivity(intent);


    } catch (
            Exception e)

    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage() + " ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    installManager.unregisterListener(splitInstallStateUpdatedListener);
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_epaper) {
        loadAndLaunchModule(EpaperModuleName, EPaperLauncherclassName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the Activity is defined in the dynamic feature, you need to call `SplitCompat.install(this)` in the `attachBaseContext` method to make sure that all new resources are available to your app.

Comment: It's not working. Is there any other way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Could you share enough of your module (e.g. the skeleton of com.bhaskar.epaper.ui.SplashActivity) to be able to replicate your issue?

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that the solution provided by [@pfmaggi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118862/pfmaggi) is correct.

It works when you pass the application context, so you have do something like:

```
class MyApplication: SplitCompatApplication() {
...
    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
        super.attachBaseContext(newBase)
        SplitCompat.install(this)
    }
...
}
```

and then add the application name in Manifest of your base module ( Note: add application name to the manifest file in your module named 'app' or the module with `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` in its build.gradle file )

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at how Dynamic Features are implemented in [this sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-dynamic-features).

There's sample code on how to open some resources, located in a dynamic module, [from the base module](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-dynamic-features/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/samples/dynamicfeatures/MainActivity.kt#L151).

Plus, the samples includes others dynamic modules with activities implemented in Java/Kotlin and native.

Keep in mind that playcore v1.3.4 includes a fix a similar bug. Be sure to use v1.3.4 or newer. The other requirement is to override the `attachBaseClassContext` in the activities you've in the dynamic modules:

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase)
    SplitCompat.install(this)
}
```

This is shown in the sample with [this abstract class.](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-dynamic-features/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/samples/dynamicfeatures/BaseSplitActivity.kt)

Comment: @Rakesh-sahu, can you please confirm if adding the attachBaseContext to your activity solved the issue? If Yes, please accept the answer